# Sytax issues for a Java beginner

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and I had an assignment to write a program which sells tickets. I have some issues that I can't really understand why they are wrong. The issues I have are in compiling.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class tickets extends ConsoleProgram {
    public static double eisitirio = 1.2;
    public void run(){
    double nomisma=readInt("Insert coins and then press 0");
    boolean synthiki=false;
    double poso=0;
    while (synthiki=false){
        while (nomisma != 0){
            if ((nomisma==0.1)||(nomisma==0.2)||(nomisma==0.5)||(nomisma==1)||(nomisma==2)||(nomisma==5)){
            poso=poso+nomisma;
            }else {
                printIn("You did not insert a supported coin, please insert another one");
            }
            nomisma=readInt("Insert coins and then press 0");
        }
        if (poso < eisitirio){
            printIn("You did not insert enough money, please insert more coins");
        }else {
            synthiki=true;
        }
    }
    printIn("Here is your ticket");
    poso=poso-eisitirio;
    double resta=0;
    if ((poso/5) > 0){
        printIn("You have change: 5 euros");
        poso = poso-5;
    }
    if ((poso/2) > 0){
        printIn("You have change: 2 euros");
        poso = poso-2;
    }
    if ((poso/1) > 0){
        printIn("You have change: 1 euros");
        poso = poso-1;
    }   
    if ((poso/0.5) > 0){
        printIn("You have change: 50 cents");
        poso = poso-0.5;
    }
    if ((poso/0.2) > 0){
        printIn("You have change: 20 cents");
        poso = poso-0.2;
    }
    if ((poso/0.1) > 0){
        printIn("You have change: 10 cents");
        poso=poso-0.1;
    }
    }

}
```

Compiling errors:

```
C:\Users\kriton\Desktop\Java>javac -cp acm.jar tickets.java
tickets.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
                                printIn("You did not insert a supported coin, please insert another one");
                                ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: class tickets
tickets.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
                        printIn("You did not insert enough money, please insert more coins");
                        ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: class tickets
tickets.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        printIn("Here is your ticket");
        ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: class tickets
tickets.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
                printIn("You have change: 5 euros");
                ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: class tickets
tickets.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
                printIn("You have change: 2 euros");
                ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: class tickets
tickets.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
                printIn("You have change: 1 euros");
                ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: class tickets
tickets.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
                printIn("You have change: 50 cents");
                ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: class tickets
tickets.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
                printIn("You have change: 20 cents");
                ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: class tickets
tickets.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
                printIn("You have change: 10 cents");
                ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: class tickets
9 errors
```

I don't know, I've tried a lot of things, but they seem really weird. I don't understand why the first if is wrong, I looked it up in the book, about ifs and booleans, but it seems correct that way.

Comment: Tip: `println` is short for ‘print line’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error: cannot find symbol

means that...

... a symbol cannot be found.

The reason of this is...

... that a symbol is not defined.

Possible solutions:

- define the symbol
- use a defined symbol instead

In your case, you are trying to call a method, with the name of `printIn`. In our case, the symbol is `printIn`. Since this is not defined, you receive the error mentioned above. You either define the symbol like this:

```
public static void printIn(text) {
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

or use `System.out.println` instead. Read more [here](http://java.about.com/od/cerrmsg/g/Definition-Cannot-Find-Symbol.htm).

Answer (score 3):

- For starters, it's `System.out.println` for the `printIn` you have there.
- `readInt` should probably be changed to:

  ```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );

  System.out.print( "Insert coins and then press 0" );
  nomisma = Integer.parseInt( br.readLine() );
  // This is the PURE implementation of the function you want; now, if you haven't defined this somewhere, it will cause you problems.
  ```

Comment: Pleasure! It's often confusing for starters to distinguish between pseudocode and normal code. Glad I was able to help. :)

Comment: @KritonGeorgiou, be sure to upvote and mark the answers if they answer the query! This helps the moderators segregate the answered questions from the unanswered ones and is also beneficial for the community. :)

Answer (score 0):

Include library and replace *printIn* with *System.out.println*